# SQL Server Dynamic Column and its counter

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

My data looks like this

[image: looking like this]

This is how I have attempted it so far
[image: my attempt]

is giving the events columns duplicated as shown in the left side query above, not sure why

Output is required in 2 formats pivot by Event Date

[image: Event Date]

and by Event Type

[image: Event Type]

I tried to insert the SQL code but it didn't work with formatting, sorry

```
-- to create a table
Create Table TestStudentEvents (Pid int, StudentID int, EventName varchar(50), EventDate DateTime);

Insert into TestStudentEvents values 
(1, 1, 'SA', '2021-05-10'),  (2, 1, 'SA', '2021-05-12'), (3, 1, 'AA', '2021-05-11'), 
(4, 2, 'SA', '2021-05-10'),  (5, 2, 'SA', '2021-05-12'), (6, 2, 'AB', '2021-05-11')

--select * from #StudentEvents



DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);    
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(EventName)
                        from TestStudentEvents AS t 
                        where  [StudentID] = 1 or [StudentID] = 2
                        group by EventName 
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

-- select @cols

SELECT @query = 'SELECT * , '+ @cols + '
FROM
(
  select distinct [EventName], COUNT(EventName) as NoOfEvents, [StudentID]
  FROM TestStudentEvents 
  where  [StudentID] =1 or [StudentID] = 2  
  group by [EventName], [StudentID]
) AS t 
PIVOT
(
  Max(NoOfEvents)
  FOR [EventName] IN (' + @cols + ')' +
                  ') p ';

  execute(@query);

  Drop table TestStudentEvents;
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors/data when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: This looks like a task for the presentation layer, not the database layer. What's with using the pivot table as you have?

Comment: The images are from Excel as I wanted to check if it can be done first

Comment: Sorry @Larnu, not sure what you mean

Comment: Read the FAQ I linked, images of code are very frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks Larnu  I have pasted my  sample test code  that I tried , but the formatting is still bad

Comment: For whatever reason, `@cols` has the `EventName`s multiple times. Given that that query has `group by EventName` I posit that it is not possible with the `select @cols` query as shown. I suspect you have a different `group by` in your real query. But as mentioned by @Larnu this really is better left to the presentation layer, SQL doesn't handle dynamic columns well

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the * with actual columns in the dynamic SQL.

Please see the db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e992dd2596df766398539ec14ea016a0).